# How do i count with datetime and list it?

Tags: python, datetime

I need help to make a code, that counts every 15 min of a day. Then I want the dates and time to be put in a list. The code needs to stop counting on Friday at 07.30 pm and then start again Monday 00:00 am.

this is what have so far

```
   import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 15, 00, 00, 00, 00)

tdelta = date.timedelta(min=15)



#date2 = date1 + timedelta
#timedelta = date1 + date2


#if day is between monday 00 and friday 19:30:
#lst.append(day)
#day = day + 15
```

i want the result to be like this...

> friday 01.05.2016 19:00pm friday 01.05.2016 19:15pm friday 01.05.2016
>   19:30pm friday 01.05.2016 19:45pm friday 01.05.2016 20:00pm Monday
>   04.05.2016 00:00am Monday 04.05.2016 00:15am Monday 04.05.2016 00:30am etc...

I am stuck at this one, hope you can help

Comment: Be clear on your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need smth like this:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 15, 00, 00, 00, 00)
tdelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
result = []
for i in range(20):
    dt += tdelta
    if (dt.isoweekday() < 5) or ((dt.isoweekday() == 5) and (dt.time() < datetime.datetime.strptime('19:30:00', '%H:%M:%S').time())):
        result.append(dt)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Below codes gives a list of dates between dateFrom to DateTo with a specific minutes range;

```
function (dateFrom, dateTo, minutes){
    let dates = [];
    let tempDate = dateFrom;
    while ( tempDate < dateTo){
       dates.push(tempDate);
       tempDate = tempDate.setMinutes(tempDate.getMinutes() + minutes);
    }
    return dates;
}
```